# Validación con pattern en input search para placa "ABC-123"

Tags: html, html5, regex

Necesito realizar una validación en HTML con el atributo `pattern` para una placa o identificación de auto con el formato `"ABC-123"` con el guión medio (`-`), en un `input type=search`.

Ya revisé en la nube y en la documentación y trate de realizarlo de muchas forma pero no me funciona. Tengo el siguiente código en el `input`:

```
<input type="search" pattern="[A-Z]+-[0-9]" name="PLACA" id="PLACA" placeholder="Buscar automotor por placa"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías considerar `[A-Z]{3}[-]\d{3}`. Donde:

- `[A-Z]{3}`: Considera solo 3 letras mayúsculas
- `[-]`: Un carácter, en tu caso el guión (-)
- `\d{3}`: Considera 3 caracteres de tipo numérico, podría ser también `[0-9]{3}`.

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="search" pattern="[A-Z]{3}[-]\d{3}" name="PLACA" id="PLACA" placeholder="Buscar automotor por placa"/>  
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Que significa "\d"?

Comment: @Davilo no hace falta corchetes alrededor del `-`. Es lo mismo que `[A-Z]{3}-\d{3}`

Comment: @Mariano es correcto, pero no veo la gravedad en su uso. De todos modos explico que significa un carácter.

Comment: @Davilo de hecho, se llama *clase de caracteres*. No es grave, pero en términos de código, sería usar `Array("-")[0]` en vez de `"-"`.

Comment: @Mariano podrías aclararnos con una respuesta y poder entenderte. =)

Comment: @Davilo no es lo que está preguntando el autor de la pregunta. Tu respuesta está bien, por eso no respondí... Lo mío fue un comentario para que mejores tu regex. Tomalo o dejalo